# What is the LaTex command for common notation for time scale as shown in picture?

Tags: symbols

What is the LaTex command for common notation for time scale as shown in picture?
[image]

Comment: Although I admittedly had a difficult time getting Detexify to find the symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\mathbb{T}` with `amssymb` loaded:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{T}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the symbol drawn by the code in answer doesn't contain empty space inside

Comment: @AneesUrRehman the image below my code block is the exact output (modulo rasterization) of the code above it. If the symbol doesn't contain empty spaces it's because of the fonts you use. Please add every font related information to your question.

Comment: Yes, it worked with Texmaker, actually it didn't worked with Scientific WorkPlace. Thank you so much.